# Mongodb - aggregation and batchSize - cursor not found after 1 minute

Tags: php, mongodb, timeout, cursor, aggregation-framework

I have an unusual mongodb cursor-timeout issue - I get a `cursor not found` error even though the timeout of 10 minutes has not been reached.

My env:

- ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- PHP 7.1.13
- libmongoc bundled version 1.8.2
- MongoDB extension version 1.3.3
- mongodb/mongodb 1.2.0

Here is some code. In short, I loop over millions of users, for each user I perform a large aggregation, loop over results with a cursor, and then run a bunch of bulk-upserts.

```
<?php

/**
 * THE AIM IS TO PERFORM A BIG AGGREGATION ON AN ENTIRE COLLECTION, MASSAGE THE RESULTS, AND WRITE INTO A PERMANENT COLLECTION.
 *
 * THE AGGREGATION IS BIG, SO IT WRITES TO DISK, AND WE ACCESS WITH A CURSOR.
 *
 * IN ORDER TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE, WE BULK-UPSERT INTO THE PERMANENT COLLECTION ON EVERY 10k DOCUMENTS.
 *
 */
class Analytics
{
    const MAX_CURSOR_PAGE_SIZE = 10000;

    public function performAnalytics($arr_user_ids)
    {
        foreach ($arr_user_ids as $item_user_id)
            $this->performUserAnalytics($item_user_id->id);
    }

    private function performUserAnalytics($userId)
    {
        // AGGREGATION QUERY
        $userItemsPage = $this->getUserItemsPage($userId);

        // BULK UPSERT
        $arrItemOps = [];
        foreach ($userItemsPage as $item_user)
        {
            array_push($arrItemOps, [
                'updateOne' => [
                    [ 'my_key' => $item_user->_id, ],
                    [ '$set' => [ 'item_ids' => $item_user->item_ids ] ],
                    [ 'upsert' => true ]
                ]
            ]);

            // BULK-UPSERT FOR PERFORMANCE
            if(count($arrItemOps) > self::MAX_CURSOR_PAGE_SIZE)
            {
                Log::info("BULK-UPSERTING USER ITEMS");
                $permanent_collection->bulkUpsert($arrItemOps);
                $arrItemOps = [];
            }
        }

        // FINAL BULK-UPSERT
        if(count($arrItemOps) > 0)
            $permanent_collection->bulkUpsert($arrItemOps);
    }

    // BIG AGGREGATION
    private function getUserItemsPage($userId)
    {
        return $items_collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$match' => [
                    'user_id' => $userId
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$group' => [
                    '_id' => '$user_id',
                    'item_ids' => [
                        '$addToSet' => '$item_id'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [ 'allowDiskUse' => true ]);
    }
}
```

The code should takes ~2 days to run. After 1.3 days I get the `cursor not found` error on the `foreach ($userItemsPage as $item_user)` line.
The thing that's giving me a headache is that I see a:

> BULK-UPSERTING USER ITEMS

log line every 50 seconds (45s to loop over 10k results, and 5s to bulk-upsert), and then the error line 1 minute after that.
Every user-analytics takes between 1-120 minutes. I have not modified the default batch-size of 101 documents.

So I'm struggling to see where the timeout error is hiding.

I have gone through @Danziger 's excellent reply here ([MongoDB - Error: getMore command failed: Cursor not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248108/mongodb-error-getmore-command-failed-cursor-not-found)) but it seems unrelated to my scenario.

And there is another related but unanswered question ([MongoDB - PHP - MongoCursorException 'Cursor not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805469/mongodb-php-mongocursorexception-cursor-not-found))

Thanks,

Comment: Seeing sporadic crashing, this time after 5 hours, on a different user

Comment: I cannot see many mongod log lines with the 'getMore' command. I suspect that mongo may not be using 101 as the default batch size, but only the _initial_ batch size. Maybe this is a difference between `find()` and `aggregate()`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I understand what is going on now, `find()` and `aggregate()` behave *differently* with respect to `batchSize`.

Find (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize):

[Find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize)

> Specifies the number of documents to return in each batch

[Aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#specify-an-initial-batch-size):

> specify an initial batch size for the cursor

So with `aggregate()`, specifying a batchSize for subsequent batches is done on the returned cursor, not within the aggregation command. However that is not possible in PHP - we do not have the same level of control on the cursor object. This means that aggregation batchSize cannot be controlled in PHP. I have a raised a ticket for this with the fine folks at mongo (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPLIB-312).

In my case, this manifested as mongo returning me a large batch (~130k documents) which could take >10min to process. I was inserting 10k documents at a time, but this did not mean that I was reading batches of 10k from mongo at a time.